# How to tweak the volume increment steps in Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, volume-control

The volume increment steps are too coarse for my taste. Is it possible to tweak this?

This has been asked for older versions of Ubuntu (some of them using Unity), but I'd like to know what is the right approach for Gnome, which is the default desktop environment in Ubuntu 18.04.h

Comment: What method do you currently use for changing the volume? Fn+volume up/down, or something else?

Comment: Indeed, `Fn + volume up/down`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hold down the `Shift` key while pressing the keyboard shortcut to change the volume.

Comment: Great! When googling for solutions to this problem I only found old information. I've never seen this. Thanks.

Comment: Might there be a way to reverse this behaviour?